# How to subcribe on WorkItem state changes on TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem

Good day!

I want to know, how to subcribe on WorkItem state changes on TFS 2010\2013?

Should i use WCF?

Please tell we the way.

Thank you.

P.S. i need to get access to tfs workitem changes via c# : when workitem changed- i want to get some notification and do some operations via c#

For example: i have console program,wich get all workitems. But it get by run sheduler.
I want to subscribe my program on some event like onWorkItemChanged: when some user change task- program get this changed and do some work.

Comment: Can not be answered because we miss context. Subscribe as get them to your program or get them via emails or for a local service to react?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different ways to achive this. You can do it directly within the process of tfs by implementing an ISubscriber and listening to the WorkitemChangedEvent:

http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/

Or using the client API you can register a wcf service to get notified for workitem changes. So you can implement the logic on a different tier.

You can find both implementations here:

http://tfswiwatcher.codeplex.com

The 2010 Version uses the client side way and the 2012 and 2013 versions are using the server side way.

Comment: And can i use client way with 2013 and 2013 versions?

Comment: Yes the client way is also possible in 2013.

Comment: Btw. the client api way for registering for notifications is just a coded alternate for the BisSubsribe tool

Comment: So, if i will use ISubscriber-should i run my programm at the same server where tfs is? or i can run it on another server?

Comment: An ISubscriber is implemented in an assembly thats running within the process of tfs. You just put the dll in the servers plugin folder.

Comment: @Scordo is the server side ISubscriber implementation is available for tfs 2017?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool [BisSubsribe](https://www.google.nl/search?q=bissubscribe&oq=bissubs&aqs=) to register for an event. It can hook up your own service to events occuring in TFS.

Answer (score 1):

TFS has capabilities to set up email notifications. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx) MSDN page for help.